# How to update a state variable in an array in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have this state and I want to update the properties `name` and `location` in a dynamic way.

```
this.state = {
  players: [{
    name: '',
    location: ''
  },
  {
    name: '',
    location: ''
  }]
}
```

The idea is that you can click a button to add another/remove a player. Per player, these input fields should appear (which I achieved), but I'm unable to update the state on change.

Preferably something like this (but I'm unable to make it work for this particular case). Unless there's a better way to achieve this of course (I'm rather new in React).

```
this.handleChange = (event) => {  let obj = {...this.state.obj }; obj [event.target.name] = event.target.value; this.setState({obj }); }
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add temporary id value to the player's list and on change pass the target id and the field changes, and change the state accordingly

```
const onPlayerChange = ({target : { id , name , vlaue}}) =>{
   const newPlayersState = this.state.players.map(player=>{
      if(player.id === id) return {...player,[name]:value}
      return player;
   })
   this.setState({players:newPlayersState})
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Where should this `id` come from exactly? I tried to put it as attribute to my form control, but that didn't work.

Comment: you can use `shortid` module for generating unique id's or you can map over it and use the index and an id

Answer (score 0):

```
addPlayer(name, location) {
  const players = {...this.state.players};
  players.push({
    name,
    location
  });
  this.setState({
    players
  });
}

removePlayer(name) {
  const players = {...this.state.players};
  this.setState({
    players: players.filter(p => p.name != name)
  });
}
```

Comment: You should not directly mutate the state.

Comment: Yes, that was my intention.